# Sequence Limit Reciprocal Law Proof

Tags: limits

I am aware that this has a duplicate but I am trying to prove it differently than others.

Proposition: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L \neq 0,$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{L}$

Proof:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$, so $\exists N_2 $st $\forall n > N_2 |a_n-L|< \epsilon$

Take N = max$(N_1,N_2); $ so $\forall n>N, |a_n-L| < \epsilon  $

and $\forall n>N_1, |a_n| < \frac{1}{|L|}$ (by Lemma)

So $|\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{L}| = \frac{|a_n-L|}{|a_n|*|L|} = |a_n-L|*\frac{1}{L}*\frac{1}{a_n}$

$<\epsilon *\frac{1}{L}*L$

$<\epsilon$

I am just having difficulty proving the Lemma, which should be $|a_n|<\frac{1}{|L|}$

Any advice?

Comment: variable is $n$ not $x$

Comment: Sorry, I copy pasted the format for fractions. Is there any other advice you can give ?

Comment: @beepbeepboop123123 Your question had a tag of just "elementary-number-theory". However, what you're asking doesn't really fit as the tag description says "Questions on congruences, linear Diophantine equations, greatest common divisor, divisibility, etc.". Instead, a tag like "limits" would be more appropriate, so I've taken the liberty of changing your tag. You may wish to check [Tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags) for any other appropriate tags to add to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof attempt has a few issues. For one, it changes the limit from $A$ to $L$ (I will use $L$ here). Also, it doesn't define what $N_1$ is, but from the context it seems to be for the minimum value where $\left|a_n - \frac{1}{L}\right| \lt \epsilon$. Finally, and most importantly, you can't prove your suggested lemma of $\left| a_n \right| \lt \frac{1}{\left| L \right|}$ because it's not necessarily true. For example, if $a_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}$, then $L = 2$, but you never have $\left|a_n\right| \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

The way I would do it instead is to expand the part in absolute values and then use the resulting inequalities to place an appropriate upper limit on $\frac{1}{\left| a_n \right|}$. In particular, you have

$$\left| a_n - L \right| \lt \epsilon \; \Rightarrow \; -\epsilon \lt a_n - L \lt \epsilon \; \Rightarrow \; -\epsilon + L \lt a_n \lt \epsilon + L \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

There are $2$ main cases to consider, i.e., $L$ being positive or negative. I'll show how to handle the positive case. First, have $\epsilon \lt \frac{L}{2}$. As such, all $3$ parts of the end of \eqref{eq1} are positive. Thus, multiplying the left & middle parts by $\frac{1}{a_n\left(L - \epsilon\right)}$ gives

$$\frac{1}{a_n} \lt \frac{1}{L - \epsilon} \lt \frac{2}{L} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

with the last inequality coming from $L - \epsilon \gt \frac{L}{2}$ by the earlier assumption. This gives that

$$\left|a_n - L\right| \times \frac{1}{L} \times \frac{1}{\left|a_n\right|} \lt \frac{2\epsilon}{L^2} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

The epsilon to choose for proving the limit of $\frac{1}{a_n}$, call it $\epsilon_2$, could be any $\epsilon_2 = \frac{2\epsilon}{L^2} \lt L$. In that case, the original epsilon would be $\epsilon = \frac{L^2\epsilon_2}{2}$ to give an appropriate $N$ to be used.

Handling the case where $L$ is negative is similar, except you need to use the right hand part of \eqref{eq1} instead and make sure to use absolute values in appropriate places. I'll leave this part to you to finish.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, but I have a couple of questions;

1) After multiplying the left and middle parts by $\frac{1}{a_n(L-\epsilon}$ how did you get $\frac{2}{L}$ on the right hand side of (2)?

2) When did we discover $L-\epsilon>\frac{L}{2}$?

3) How did you realize to set $\epsilon<\frac{L}{2}$?

Comment: @beepbeepboop123123 You're welcome. As for (1), if $a$ and $b$ are positive quantities with $a \gt b$, then multiplying by $\frac{1}{ab}$ gives $\frac{1}{b} \gt \frac{1}{a}$. In this case, $L - \epsilon \gt \frac{L}{2} \; \Rightarrow \; \frac{2}{L} \gt \frac{1}{L - \epsilon}$. For (2), since I chose $\epsilon \lt \frac{L}{2}$, then $-\epsilon \gt -\frac{L}{2} \; \Rightarrow \; L - \epsilon \gt \frac{L}{2}$. For (3), I needed to set a reasonable upper bound on $\epsilon$ to get a good upper bound in my eq. (2). $\frac{L}{2}$ works, but I could've used others, like $\frac{L}{3}$, instead.